# .htaccess - grab entire url while placing last section -([0-9]{1,5}) into second variable

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Unlike most htaccess requests, where I can simply use the following code to grab the entire URL.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

What I need to do, is add paging without the use of a directory ( /page/# ) in the address. So unlike /page/# in the url, the paging is just adding a dash and a number at the end of the url, such as " -3 for page three, etc.

I've tried several rewrite Rules, but I don't believe I understand apache rewriting well enough because my regular use of paging, doesn't work when applying a catchall expression.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)-([0-9]{1,5})$ /index.php?do=something&url=$1&page=$2 [L] ## Error In? (.+)?
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?do=something&url=$1 [L,QSA] ## Works
```

In the other urls, which contain direct directories such as "something", the paging will work fine.

```
RewriteRule ^something/([a-z]{1,6})/(.*)-([0-9]{1,5})$ /index.php?do=first&what=$1&url=$2&page=$3 [L]
```

What do I have to fix in the code for catchall paging. What am I missing? The address WILL have dashes, and sometimes slashes for directories.
ERROR Code:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)-([0-9]{1,5})$ /index.php?do=this&url=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Currently looks exactly like the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)-([0-9]{1,5})$ /index.php?do=lists&url=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?do=lists&url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

If I remove The line "RewriteRule ^(.+)-([0-9]{1,5})$ /index.php?do=lists&url=$1&page=$2 [L]" - everything works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RewriteCond` is only applicable to very next `RewriteRule`. Try this code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.+?)-([0-9]{1,5})$ /index.php?do=lists&url=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?do=lists&url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Guess I'll go learn more about RewriteCond :) Thank you, Anubhava

Answer (score 1):

AHh I see now.  The RewriteCond before makes ALL the difference. A set of rewrite conditions only applies to a single redirect rule. You may need to do this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)-([0-9]{1,5})$ /index.php?do=lists&url=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?do=lists&url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: No fix. I did have [L] previously added, removed it for testing. I updated the question to include the exact final lines of the htaccess. If I remove that one line, everything works fine. So it's just the line that seems to be the problem.

{RewriteRule ^(.+)-([0-9]{1,5})$ /index.php?do=lists&url=$1&page=$2 [L]}

Comment: @JamesCordeiro See updated answer. You added context makes a big difference.